# Orange backgroundColor onClick in Android Custom Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner, background-color

I have an unusual problem in my application. I am using [Material Spinners' library](https://github.com/jaredrummler/Material-Spinner) and when I select an item from `dropdown menu`, I get this weird orange background color.

**Example:**

[image: Example]

I have exact same problem on my `Caldroid` calendar and it only happens for the background color when I click an item. I don't have this color set in my values and I don't know what to do. I need to change this color to something that is more suitable for my application.

I tried changing the `colorPrimary`, `colorHighlighted` and stuff like that in the `AppTheme` but it was no use.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: any solution with this?

Comment: I ended up using a different library I believe

Comment: oh i didnt event see that you're using that library. im getting this orange with the default android menu

Comment: try setting custom style to that view or theme with changing the color attributes in the styles.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating a custom selector and set as background of spinner. 
First create xml file custom_slector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/selected_item_color" />
<item android:drawable="@android:color/default_color" />
</selector>
```

Then set this as your background in spinner

```
android:background = "@drawable/custom_selector"
android:drawSelectorOnTop = "true"
```

Comment: It changes the color of main spinner but not the background color of it's items